# TypeScript on MacOC

Tags: typescript, npm

Добрый день подскажите как решить проблему с моим маком, он не видит tsc? Из-за чего не компилируются файлы.

Написала npm install -g typescript

потом пробую скомпилировать файл app.ts в app.js,а мне выдает bash: tsc: command not found

подскажите как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Если ваша TSC команда не запускается на MacOS после установки TypeScript (используя следующую команду: $ sudo npm install -g typescript, удостовертесь Node /bin путь добавлен в переменную PATH в .bash_profile.

Откройте .bash_profile : $ open ~/.bash_profile;

Убедитесь/отредактируйте bash профиль и включите следующую строку (используя ваш текстовый редактор):

export PATH="$PATH:"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/bin"";

Загрузите последний bash профиль используя терминал : source ~/.bash_profile;
Наконец, запустите команду: $ tsc --version.

Переведено с https://stackoverflow.com/a/53796405/12350924